# Fetching Core Data entities, but not sub-entities

Tags: cocoa, core-data

Say I have entities organized in a hierarchy with `Parent` being the root entity and `Child` being a subclass of `Parent`.  I'd like to setup an `NSArrayController` to fetch only entities of `Parent`, but not `Child`.

If you set the Entity Name of the array controller in Interface Builder to `Parent`, it fetches all `Parent` and `Child` entities.  I originally tried setting the array controller's fetch predicate in Interface Builder to:

```
entity.name == "Parent"
```

This worked for an XML store, but when I switched to a SQLite store, it no longer worked.  I get the following error:

```
keypath entity.name not found in entity <NSSQLEntity xxx>
```

As a work around, I am setting up a filter predicate (with the same `entity.name` predicate as above) in my `awakeFromNib` to filter only Parent entities.  Apparently, that predicate is valid once the entities are in memory, but you can't use it in a SQL-backed fetch predicate.

Is there a way to fetch only `Parent` entities, but not `Child` entities using a fetch predicate that works with a SQLite store?  It seems wasteful to pull in entities that you're only going to ignore with the filter predicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried using `includesSubentities`, but it ended up not working completely. It turns out changes to subentities cause the array controller's content to get updated without doing a fetch if you have "automatically prepares content" set to "Yes", thus bypassing the custom fetch predicate.  The backtrace shows `setContent:` being called in response to MOC notifications.

The only way I've found to do this reliably is to use a filter predicate.

Comment: In addition to Dave Dribin's answer above... also make sure that you set the clearsFilterPredicateOnInsertion to NO so that your filter does not get cleared out as soon as you insert or delete something (you can do this in code or IB).

Answer (score 7):

Leopard introduced the `includesSubentities` property to NSFetchRequest for exactly this purpose.  You'll have to subclass your NSObjectController or NSArrayController to provide the fetch request it will use via its `defaultFetchRequest` property, or to change the fetch request it uses by overriding its `-fetchWithRequest:...` method.