# Is the Core Data database deleted from the device when an app is deleted?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm seeing an error with Core Data that seems to indicate that the old database is not being deleted when I delete the app from my device. Here are the steps I'm taking to do this:

1. Delete the app from my device (tap & hold on the app, then tap the delete button).
2. Install the app from [TestFlight](http://www.testflightapp.com/).
3. Run the app. It starts and runs fine - until it makes a Core Data query that causes it to crash. The root cause of the crash is 'keypath bar not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Foo id=3>'

Now, based on the error stated in step 3, it may seem that 'bar' just doesn't exist on Foo and that my issue is with the Core Data model. However, the same code runs on the Simulator without issue and even runs fine on device when connected through Xcode. (I've verified a number of times that the code I'm using in Xcode to run on the Simulator and device is the same as the code in my TestFlight builds.) The problem only exists when installing via TestFlight, but I see no reason to blame TestFlight for my problems.

The same issue happens for another person on my team following the same steps, so the problem is not specific to my device. The app is not using iCloud, MobileMe, or any other syncing functionality.

Is everything Core Data-related deleted when I delete the app from my device? Does Core Data deletion or initialization behavior change depending on how the app is installed on the device?

Comment: Are you using any iCloud/MobileMe syncing? eg prefs or objects being saved across devices. Although that may not answer why it works when not using TestFlight - but then @steven-fisher's comment about build configurations may apply.

Comment: I'm not using syncing of any kind. I've already tried other configurations and have the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the files may not be deleted off simulator or in the case of a development build on device. This has something to do with Xcode not wanting to have to reinstall the entire app bundle from scratch every time it builds during development. Instead of trashing everything, it just alters what was changed. This can cause problem e.g. .xcdatamodel files don't seem to be reliably removed from the simulator when the file is removed from the build target.

However, on a release build on device, deleting the app will delete all the files in the apps sandbox i.e. everywhere the app can write.

This will not be the case on a jailbroken device.

### Update:

After reading the updated parent I would note that this error:

```
keypath bar not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Foo id=3>
```

... is generated when you try to access a keypath that the entity doesn't support. This error almost always occurs inside the predicate of a fetch request. A common cause is trying to fetch against a transient attribute. (Fetches run against the store and transient attributes by definition do not exist in the store.)

However, I have seen exactly this sort of error crop up with the development install problems I described above.

Since this is true:

> The problem only exists when installing via TestFlight...

... I don't think that:

> ...but I see no reason to blame TestFlight for my problems

... is really justified. If everything works unless you use TestFlight then it seems reasonable to conclude that TestFlight is triggering the problem.

Comment: This is a release build on device (not jailbroken), so it sounds like everything should be deleted. Still, it seems like something's hanging around. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The problem is no longer happening, and I'm not really sure what fixed it. I'm accepting this answer for its thoroughness (and because it *does* in fact answer the question of whether Core Data is deleted).

Comment: Switching to a release build and running that on the simulator fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

Deleting an app deletes its sandbox. That includes core data files.

At the risk of offering an obvious suggestion, have you built with the same build configuration? Your build to TestFlight probably uses a Release or AdHoc configuration, your device build probably uses Debug.

Comment: If all Core Data files are deleted, how does data migration work?

Comment: Does Apple have documentation on this topic? I've searched and haven't found anything related to this.

Comment: I tried building with a different configuration but still had the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Did you force close the app before you deleted it? Try force closing before deleting next time

Also in the project itself try a clean before you build the project, the simulator might be detecting entities that the phone isn't

Found a few problems with the same error type but they're all naming errors and I assume yours worked the first time?
I've never used testflight as I compile from my laptop but is there a way to clear the version from that to make absolutely sure the version you're working on is 100% accurate and working?

Try checking out these links: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182969/core-data-keypath-error-not-found-in-entity-nssqlentity-studies-id-3) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493108/core-data-keypath-objectid-not-found-in-entity) and [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298013/fetching-core-data-entities-but-not-sub-entities)